# How to download multiple torrent links using transmission-daemon?

Tags: command-line, server, bittorrent, transmission

I am using transmission-daemon on my server with the WEB GUI.
I was wondering if instead of each time clicking add torrent then paste the magnet link, I could instead call it in the terminal (SSH) with a command with a file (like for example with wget) then it will download the torrents which links are in the file.

Comment: To download torrents or magnet links from the CLI worth mentioning [`ariac`](https://aria2.github.io/)

Answer (score 8):

This will do the job.

**For `.torrent` files:**

First, you need to upload the `.torrent` files to a directory on your server. Then, please follow the steps below:

- Open a terminal and **make sure** you `cd` to the directory containing the `.torrent` files.
- To add **a single** `.torrent` file to `transmission-daemon`, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a torrent_file_name.torrent
```

- To add **all** `.torrent` files in the directory to `transmission-daemon`, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.torrent' -exec transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a {} \;
```

---

**For magnet URLs:**

- Create a file and name it `magnet.links` and add the magnet URLs one per line to the file. Please avoid crating any blank lines. Add the first link in the first line and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then add the second link in the second line and so on. Do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after the last line, just save the file and exit.
- Open a terminal and `cd` to the directory that contains the `magnet.links` file.
- Copy and paste the following code in the terminal and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
file="magnet.links"
while IFS= read -r line
do
transmission-remote -n 'transmission:transmission' -a $line
done <"$file"
```

Comment: How was this not accepted?  Great answer

Comment: Great answer! Been struggling to add multiple torrents via ssh on a dedicated server.