# Deluge keeps giving problems no matter how hard I try

Tags: server, permissions, bittorrent

I originally wanted to post this on the Deluge forums. The problem is that to sign up for an account, you have to answer a question that I genuinely don't know the answer to:
[image: Question on deluge forums]

But now the problems:

1. When I do `deluge-console cache` (but it can be everything, not only cache), it gives the following error everytime:

   ```
   Could not connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:58846
     Password does not match
   ```

   When doing `sudo -u deluge deluge-console cache`, it does work but I don't want to do that. I don't want to use sudo and run it with a certain user. I just want to do `deluge-console cache` and it should work.
2. When making any request to `deluge-console`, it always gives the following error (ontop of the error described in problem 1):

   ```
    Unable to initialize gettext/locale!
   'ngettext'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/deluge/i18n/util.py", line 118, in setup_translation
         builtins.__dict__['_n'] = builtins.__dict__['ngettext']
   KeyError: 'ngettext'
   ```
3. Everytime that I restart `deluged`, I get this message in the webui:
   [image: Connection Manager]

   I have never seen this before.
4. Doing `sudo systemctl status deluged.service deluge-web.service` shows the following errors:

   ```
   mrt 12 14:50:28 Waveserver deluged[20344]: builtins.TypeError: findCaller() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
   ```
5. In the webui, it shows the following in the bar at the bottom:
   [image: Bar at webui]
6. Sonarr and Radarr aren't able to connect and 'upload' torrents to Deluge.
7. I have already completly uninstalled Deluge twice but when installing again, deluge-web starts at my custom set port. Which is strange because that would mean that it didn't completely uninstall.

Deluge is a great piece of software but I'm done with it if stuff like this keeps going on. I want to set it up/fix it in such a way that I will NEVER have an error or problem again with it. Because I'm done with all the problems it is giving.

Comment: `transmission-daemon` is an alternative. See an [example](https://askubuntu.com/q/1117507)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first problem, you write Linux with capital L (otherwise it won't work):
https://zordekai.blogspot.com/2019/08/deluge-form-riddle-what-answer-to-above.html

Since I don't have rep to comment, I answered to first question, so others can use the answer and maybe you can post the main question in their forums.

Comment: Thanks man. I couldn't find the answer to the question anywhere!