# Want a CLI interface to Transmission: transmission-remote, transmission-cli, transmission-remote-cli?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, transmission

The Ubuntu 20.04 package `transmission-cli` says:

> This package contains a (deprecated) stand-alone command-line client, transmission-remote to interface with transmission-daemon and tools to create, edit and inspect torrent files.

And indeed, looking at the `transmission-cli` package, I see [it includes](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/transmission-remote.1.html) a `/usr/bin/transmission-remote`

On the other hand, the Transmission [project github](https://github.com/transmission/transmission) says:

> Prior to development of transmission-remote, the standalone client transmission-cli was created. Limited to a single torrent at a time, transmission-cli is deprecated and exists primarily to support older hardware dependent upon it. In almost all instances, transmission-remote should be used instead.

So which is it?  Is `transmission-remote` deprecated, or not?  And what is it's relation to `transmission-cli`?  In addition, looking on the web I find a [transmission-remote-cli](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/transmission-remote-cli.1.html) in 16.04, though it's not in the 20.04 repos.

I just want a CLI interface to Transmission so I can do some scripting.  Can someone please clear up what I'm looking at here?

**Edit:** To put it simply, I'd like to get clear if the `transmission-remote` that the transmission project github page says replaced `transmission-cli` is the same as the `transmission-remote` in the Ubuntu 20.04 package named `transmission-cli`.

Comment: `transmission-remote` Has been and is still working … [usage example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117507/how-to-download-multiple-torrent-links-using-transmission-daemon/1165694#1165694)

Comment: @Raffa - I'm trying to work out if the `transmission-remote` that the transmission project github page says replaced `transmission-cli` is the same as the `transmission-remote` in the Ubuntu 20.04 package named `transmission-cli`.  Are you clear on this?  I added the question to the OP.

Comment: @Raffa Deprecated does not mean that it doesn't work, it means it's no longer supported, so if there are program breaking bugs, they will no longer be fixed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The description of the package was [written ten years ago](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/transmission/-/commit/951b345a3fa521ae7eb2e48b09ba13301c0690cb#58ef006ab62b83b4bec5d81fe5b32c3b4c2d1cc2_48_50). The text in the README, however, was added only [four years ago](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/commit/950387ab5a443629598f93c057f41150707866ab). It's safe to say that the description needs to be updated. You might want to file a bug (probably with Debian as well) to get it updated and clarified.

Note that `transmission-remote-cli` is a separate project. The `transmission` README is talking about [`transmission-remote`](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/master/utils/transmission-remote.1) (source file [`utils/remote.c`](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/8566df069899ce8923463cadeb0ff66d4544991a/utils/remote.c)) from the same repo, which is indeed present in [Ubuntu 20.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/transmission-remote.1.html) (and [other current versions](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=impish&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=transmission-remote)).

Comment: Thanks muru. Are you clear if the `transmission-remote` in the 20.04 package transmission-cli is the `transmission-remote` that the transmission project github page says has replaced transmission-cli?

Comment: @Diagon yes. You can compare the source code of [the `transmission-remote` manpage](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/2.94/daemon/transmission-remote.1) with [the actual Ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/transmission-remote.1.html). Also see [the commit moving the `transmission-remote` files to `utils`](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/commit/204e9b04f5319f32e4e07a0d7250328bcff215b4), which make it pretty clear that `utils/remote.c` is `transmission-remote`. (Also, apologies, some of the links in my post were broken - I fixed them now.)

Comment: Ok, I swear that some day soon I'm absolutely going to learn git and github so I can dig up things like this.  Too many times I've had to learn that the real documentation is the code.

Answer (score 14):

[transmission-cli](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/net/transmission-cli) is a very simple CLI utility with no TUI/Ncurses interface. It's for entering single commands that interact with the Transmission Daemon. This should be suitable for scripting purposes, but the package is deprecated.

[transmission-remote](https://github.com/transmission/transmission) is a CLI utility included in the Transmission package. Similar to transmission-cli, this should be suitable for scripting purposes, but this package is still updated.

[transmission-remote-cli](https://github.com/fagga/transmission-remote-cli) is a TUI (text user interface) application with an actual user interface for navigating and working with torrents. However, this package is also deprecated.

For more recent forks of a TUI package, you should look at one of these:

- [stig](https://github.com/rndusr/stig) - looks like development is ongoing, but is in alpha state
- [tremc](https://github.com/tremc/tremc) - looks like development is slow, but may be more stable

Comment: Thanks, artur.  I've used stig forever and it's *fantastic*!  I'll have a look at tremc, too.  What I'm not clear on is if the new CLI client `transmission-remote`, as mentioned on the project github page, is the same as the one included in the `transmission-cli` Ubuntu package.

Comment: I agree it's pretty confusing since the names are so similar. I've updated my post to also include `transmission-remote`.

Comment: Artur - thanks, but actually ... `transmission-remote` is in the `transmission-cli` package!  There's the confusion.... Edit: Ok, it seems muru has dug up the answer to the issue.  I've upvoted yours because it's a great answer, but accepted his as he was able to go diggin in the code.